# SharePoint 2013 workflow in Project server 2013 send email functionality gives '500' error

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow, project-server

Whenever I start workflow it automatically gets cancelled and gives '500' error. And here is screen shots of error.

I am using send email functionality in workflow, and it gives below error.

Please help me out on this.

[image: Image for Error description]

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to validate the log files on the web server to see what the actual error is.  I can say, from experience, that the issue is likely with either the value entered workflow email in the "To:" address or the user profile is missing some information, namely the field with the internal name "EMail" field (which may be renamed to something such as "work email".)

You can view the user information list for users with a blank "EMail" column  with the following URL:

https://YourPWAserver/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx?FilterField1=EMail&FilterValue1=

In my environment, we had several users with the actual value of "undefined" iun the "EMail" column which I was able to view with the following URL:

https://YourPWAserver/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx?FilterField1=EMail&FilterValue1=undefined

Comment: Hello PapaDenial, 

Thanks for reply. But i have already provided work email for particular user. And i think this issue is something else. Not related to what you said.

Answer (score 0):

500 error it's an error email. If it's cancelled its because an error of one of your steps, if not you would get a suspended state.